# Generate create table statements in code like visual studio integration project import/export wizard

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

In a visual studio integration services project you can use the import/export wizard to generate a package which contains a Control Flow Execute SQL task. The Execute SQL task gets an automatically generated create table statement in the SQLStatement property. I would like to access this functionality for generating create table statements through .net code, without using the wizard. Does anybody know if this is exposed anywhere in the SSIS .NET api?

Answer (score 1):

I like using [SMO - SQL Management Objects](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162175.aspx) for stuff like this.